# Apply the value of a dropdown on a website in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, excel, vba

I want to apply the value of a dropdown on a website.

There is a button tag in the source HTML code. After clicking the button (button.click), I select the dropdown value for all tag having class as "dropdownAvailable" from the Option tag.

Although the value of the dropdown seems to change, the page doesn't change accordingly.

The HTML code for the Select tag is like below.

```
    <select name="dropdown_selected_size" autocomplete="off" data-a-touch-header="Size" id="selected_size" class="a-native-dropdown">
        <option id="native_size_-1" data-a-id="size_-1" selected>Select</option>
        <option class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_0" data-a-id="size_0" data-a-html-content="40.5">40.5</option>
        <option class="dropdownUnavailable" id="native_size_1" data-a-id="size_1" data-a-html-content="40.5">40.5</option>
        <option class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_2" data-a-id="size_2" data-a-html-content="41">41</option>
        <option class="dropdownUnavailable" id="native_size_3" data-a-id="size_3" data-a-html-content="41">41</option>
        <option class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_4" data-a-id="size_4" data-a-html-content="42">42</option>
    </select>
```

I have tried all of the below options for the dropdown to be selected.

1. ie.document.getElementById("selected_size").onchange
2. ie.document.getElementById("selected_size").FireEvent ("onchange")
3. ie.document.getElementById("selected_size").getElementsByTagName("option")(n).Click
4. ie.document.getElementById("selected_size").Click
5. Application.SendKeys "{TAB}"
6. Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
7. Application.SendKeys "~"

I'm using IE Version 11 and MS Excel 2013.

Comment: Right below the Select tag, there is a call to the javascript.

  <script language="javascript" >
  if(typeof(TwisterNonJs) == 'undefined')
  {
  window.TwisterNonJs = {};
  TwisterNonJs.handleDropDown = [];
  }
  TwisterNonJs.handleDropDown[0] = function(){
  var twisterUpdateButton = "submit.twisterUpdateButton_0"
  document.getElementById("dummySubmitButton").setAttribute("name",twisterUpdateButton);
  document.forms['twister'].submit();
  };
  document.getElementById("selected_size").onchange = function(){
  TwisterNonJs.handleDropDown[0]();
  };
  </script>

Comment: IE is bad, try using [chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I'm very paranoid about readystate after every interaction with website, sometimes even this is not enough and you need to execute your code only after some loading window disappears. You must also remember that IE has big trouble with dropdowns and often requires double clicking dropdown value to choose it.

```
'requires Microsoft HTML Object Library, Microsoft Internet Controls reference

Dim htmlele As ihtmlelement
Dim colele As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'navigating and other code

Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And ie.Busy = False
    DoEvents
Loop

set htmlele = ie.document.getElementByID("selected_size")
htmlele.click

Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And ie.Busy = False
    DoEvents
Loop

Set colele = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("option")
For Each htmlele In colele
    If htmlele.className = "dropdownAvailable" Then
        htmlele.click
        Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And ie.Busy = False
          DoEvents
        Loop
        'the code       
    End If
Next htmlele
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However the change didn't work. Meanwhile, I tried using SENDKEYS and it worked.

1. htmlele.click
2. Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}"          
3. Application.SendKeys "~"

This did the work for me. Now, I'm wondering whatg would happen if i change the control from IE to another application when the macro is running.

Answer (score 0):

I always try to avoid using the sendKey function when automating DOM. There is always unforeseen delays in the UI, and the right element must be active as well as the IE window has to be the currently active OS window. This means that you can't easily debug your code.
Instead you should try to select the option element and set the attribute to selected. kinda like so

```
Set list = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".dropdownAvailable option")
For Each option in list 
 if option.innerText = yourMatchStr Then
  call option.setAttribute("selected", "selected")
  Exit For
 end if 
next option
```

Now the option item is selected, but sometimes the selection is not visible in the view. sometimes that doesn't mean anything the change is registered when the page is reloaded or when user presses other buttons on the page